# Centering MenuItems in second ActionBar?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

So I am trying to center my icons like this image from Google Developer:

[image]

My second row is actually just below the top row (which is also actionbar tabs without a title or icon enabled in the activity). So, right now, as I've added in my three buttons (just text, no icons) they stack on the right side of the bar, and I can't seem to find anything in the docs about centering. Any ideas?

Relevant code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_demos"          
          android:title="Chart +/-"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_data"          
          android:title="Datas"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_reset"          
          android:title="Reset"
          android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

manifest line:

```
<activity android:name="polling.Chart" android:label="Chart"
        android:icon="@drawable/chart512"     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
```

Main Activity:

```
    bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chartsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the split action bar option. All items which does not fix in the top action bar will be shown in the second action bar at the bottom of your screen. The remaining items will be centered within the second action bar.

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getSherlock().setUiOptions(ActivityInfo.UIOPTION_SPLIT_ACTION_BAR_WHEN_NARROW);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```